# Why is magento delivering images as https on http site

Tags: magento-enterprise, media, https

I have a magento website with multiple stores.

In the basic configuration we use https://exampleBackend.com as Unsecure Url and Secure Url because the backend has to be in https.

On each store we use for example http://exampleFrontendEnglish.com as Unsecure Url and https://exampleFrontendEnglish.com as Secure Url.
The setting for media is {{unsecure_base_url}}media/ for all stores.

When I visit one of the stores (for example http://exampleFrontendEnglish.com) the site is loaded with http but all the pictures are tried to be loaded via https which fails and I have no clue why that happens.

If I change the secure base url to http everything is loaded with http but I do not have any https anymore for secure parts.

Has someone a clue why the stores are loaded in http but medias in https?
Any hint is welcome

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to your question but a solution to your problem: to use https in the backend you don't need to change the unsecure base URL, instead set the configuration "use secure URL in admin" to "yes"

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System/Configuration` then select Scope of your website.

and use secure URL in admin to yes.